# pybrain prediction is only float. I need integer, boolean and string

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, pybrain

I am using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962274/dont-print-results-of-a-function) and try to predict the final number of a sequence.

The problem is that the neural network predict all the time float numbers.

Is there any way to fix the type of the sample? I want to test with integers, boolean and strings.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an integer you simply round the float, probably expanding the range (if the output is in `0..1` and you want integers as up as `100` for example, multiply the returned value with `100` and round it afterwards).

To get booleans simply round the value to `0` or `1`.

To get strings is tricky. If you know in advance what type of strings are expected you can tabulate them and use the above integer mechanism to get the index of the string to be returned. On the other hand, if you don't know the strings and want to create them dynamically at runtime, you're in for some big trouble: you will have to get each character in its own according to some grammar, possibly.

Edit: The other option is to have the output layer of the network consist of a layer of (usually softmax) neurons each one being responsible for a value of the output. For example, if you want to have only 10 integral outputs you'll have 10 output neurons and the one with the higher output will be the integer output. Something along the lines of [competitive learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Competitive_learning)

Comment: So with this way, I probably lose in accuracy. I did it with the round way for 0,1 before, but I have around 50% correct results and I thought that this was the problem.

Comment: Update your network configuration - more complex hidden layers. There is no other way to convert from floats to integers.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your help. Set your answer as the best one